# "Декоративно-прикладное творчество" — можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Встретила в тексте выражение "декоративно-прикладное творчество" и как-то оно меня резануло. Если бы было "искусство", тогда понятно. Но — творчество?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По крайней мере, так говорят. И такое употребление  закреплено в документах. Декоративно-прикладное творчество - раздел школьного курса "Технология" (то, что раньше называлось "трудовое обучение"" или попросту "труд"). Это такое обобщающее понятие для бисероплетения, вышивания, вязания, выжигания, резьбы по дереву, лепки и т.п.